# shell: Crontab expression for 13th working days

Tags: linux, shell, unix

please i want to create crontab that should runs evry 13th working day at 9am.

Im tried this row but still not giving what i want.

```
0 9 13 * 1-5
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script to run every day and put a condition inside of the script to check if the current day is the 13 th and is business day.

for python scrips, i have used :
`if( (len(pd.bdate_range(first_day_oftm,current_day))-1==0)  ):`   to see if the current_day it's the first working day of the month ( for example ) .

Good luck !